# How can i Pass parameter to Constructor?

Tags: java, android, apollo

i have auto generated class with constructor

```
Userinput(Input<Integer>id, Input<String>name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
})
```

how to pass value to constructor.

Comment: I suggest you read some java tutorials/docs, this is super basic java.

Comment: Like any other constructor. What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
Userinput userInput = new Userinput(1, "test");
```